# How to select the organisation and it's next event?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the two tables in my SQL Server database, `organisation` and `event`.

One organisation has multiple events. Each event has it's own `date`.

I'm trying to retrieve the next/upcoming events date with it's organisation's `name`. The next event is where the events date equals today or the days after.

I tried something like this (which obviously doesn't work):

```
var queryResults = (from o in context.Organisations
             join e in context.Events on o.Id equals e.Organisation.Id
             where e.PremiereDateTime >= DateTime.UtcNow
             orderby e.PremiereDateTime ascending
             select o, e);
```

I tried to do a `group by`, but I failed. I made it work with a plain T-SQL query, but I want to do it with Entity Framework.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that I'm trying to select the organisation's name only once with the date of the next event. Each organisation should have only the next upcoming event.

**UPDATE #2**

Desired output:

- `organisation1` next event: `date3`
- `organisation2` next event: `date4`

**UPDATE #3**

This is what I have right now:

```
var result = from org in context.Organisations
             join sorg in context.SubOrganisations on org.Id equals sorg.Organisation.Id into sorg2
             from s in sorg2.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join ev in context.Events on s.Id equals ev.SubOrganisation.Id into ev2
             from e in ev2.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
                 {
                    Name = org.Name,
                    UpcomingEvent = (from ee in s.Events
                                     where ee.PremiereDateTime >= DateTime.UtcNow
                                     orderby ee.PremiereDateTime ascending
                                     select ee).FirstOrDefault()
                };
```

Comment: You will need to select an anonymous type if you want both the Organisation and Event data in the same object

Comment: Do you have a navigational property `.Events` on `Organisation`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var result =
    context
    .Organisations
    .Select(org =>
        new
        {
            Name = org.Name, //Assuming that you have a `Name` property on Organisation
            UpcommingEvent = 
                org.Events
                .Where(e => e.PremiereDateTime >= DateTime.UtcNow)
                .OrderBy(e => e.PremiereDateTime)
                .FirstOrDefault()
        })
    .ToList();
```

This starts from organizations. For each one, it selects its name and the first event that starts after `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Please note that `UpcommingEvent` would be `null` for organizations that don't have an upcoming event.

Here is how the same query can be done with query syntax:

```
var result =
    from org in context.Organisations
    select new
    {
        Name = org.Name,
        UpcommingEvent = (from e in org.Events
            where e.PremiereDateTime >= DateTime.UtcNow
            orderby e.PremiereDateTime ascending
            select e).FirstOrDefault()

    };
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you do it in query syntax if it's not too much to ask?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Let me try it. :)

Comment: I get the same organisation multiple times now, as many as there are events for that organisation. I need to get each organisation only once and the next/upcoming event for each organisation. Do i need a `group by` for that or should a `FirstOrDefault()` call fix that?

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. Did you test the code as is? Can you include the entity classes in your code?

Comment: Could it be failing because i have added another inner join? I have SubOrganisation entity as well... And the Event entity is the child of SubOrganisation entity. And SubOrganisation is the child of Organisation. When i started the question i wanted to do it more simple... But now this is causing the problem i guess. Your code works probably.

Comment: I have added the code which i'm trying now at the end of my question.

Comment: Edited again. Now it's exactly the same i have right now.

Comment: Could this affect it? Or shouldn't the inner join play a role here?

Comment: @JoSmo, try to use my code, but replace `from e in org.Events` with `from e in org.SubOrganizations.SelectMany(x => x.Events)`.

Comment: Works perfect now. Thank you very much for showing me how to do this properly. I learned something new and useful today. :)